# Loop to upload list images one by one

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to **upload multiple images one by one**, like once user do tap on upload all button, it has to start with first image visible in a list, once first image will be uploaded to server then automatically has to start second for upload but after one or two second interval and same for all available images in a list.

This is my code, which allow me to upload single image:-

**Code to upload single image**

```
    // btnUpload
    holder.uploadImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Upload
        startUpload(position);
            }
        });
```

I am using **below** code, but its **uploading/syncing** all images at same time, my mean together, like i have **500 images** in a list so its **uploading all 500 together** and as a result i am getting error when internet connection goes down and many times not getting accurate status of uploaded images !

```
    private SparseBooleanArray flags = new SparseBooleanArray();

    // At onClick, set all the flags to indicate that some data needs to be synced
    ImageButton buttonUploadAll = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sync_btn);
    buttonUploadAll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

             for(int position=0; position<listView.getAdapter().getCount(); position++)
             {
                 flags.put(position, true);
             }

             // Calling this would ensure a call to getView() on every
             // visible child of the listview. That is where we will check if
             // the data is to be synced and displayed or not
             ((BaseAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
             }
          });

      @Override
      // In getView of the listview's adapter
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      // If this item is to be synced
      if(flags.get(position)) {
        startUpload();

        // Mark as synced
        flags.put(position, false);
    }

    // Rest of the method that draws the view....
}
```

that's why i want to **upload multiple images one by one** (in a queue manner)

Comment: Did you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422541/how-to-send-multiple-images-to-server-using-multipartentity-from-android

Comment: are you able to upload a single image  ?

Comment: yes i am able to upload single image @Kedarnath thanks for coming

Comment: ok, and have you tried my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21907011/3330969) ?

Comment: yes i tried your answer please see my edited answer with Log

Comment: Well, in your code, you are uploading only one image at time, which is based on position, correct ?

Comment: yes exactly ... @Kedarnath

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57260/discussion-between-kedarnath-and-moon).

Comment: @Kedarnath where you gone buddy ?

Comment: @Kedarnath bro sorry was went to meeting in mid of conversion

Comment: You can make an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) that uploads the image. You'll need to set a flag whether the image has been uploaded. Even if you start multiple services, intent service will make sure images get uploaded one by one.

Comment: @AnkitPopli yes i agree with you and getting your point, as you can see my existing code buttonUploadAll i was using flag, but i am little bit confuse, can you show me the way, by making changes into my existing code and place your solution as answer so i will accept that for others

Comment: best way is to give array of all image to be uploaded to AsyncTask and in doInbackground method just loop through the image array one by one. From onProgressUpdate of AsyncTask, using interface object you can intimate the caller method to update flag for the images uploaded, so in case you face any issue in the uploading process and need to restart, you can start with the image which is not uploaded

Comment: @Moon you will need that flag to be persistent since Service may go down temporarily, I'll post an answer ASAP, but it will still take me some time. Meanwhile, you can work on making your flag persistent.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela need solution anyhow please show your idea by modifying my existing code

Comment: @AnkitPopli sure..  will wait..

Comment: Added my answer below, check.

Comment: Moon, You have the answers right here... and good ones too. I don't think I can give a better answer than what you already have been presented with. And as @AnkitPopli suggested, you can start by making the flag persistent.

Comment: @moon i hv created a app which is doing same thing successfully, i hv few questions regarding same in ur code, let me know when ur free on mtetno room , i hope u remember our conversation in SO

Comment: @adcom where can i catch you ? yes i am still looking for solution

Comment: can u plz come on chat room or gmail?

Comment: ok i wanna chat come on mtetno room delete above comment

Comment: Maybe what you can do is, use the service class to upload the images and post the progress with the image id for the UI to update. While user click over the button to upload the image, just simply put this image id or what you have to represent it uniquely, to the database, where your service will pickup the one image to upload, process it and after success, pick another and so on.

Comment: hi @Moon i hv posted answer and test code , let me know if any issues..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have tried to write a service which will upload image from shared pref one by one :
Note : i hv hardcoded some of things here like image are from sdcard so path is hardcoded, images names are hardcoded, so plz change it appropriately and try out below code , i hv tested and worked for me

Below code contains **Service**, **Activity**[upload button, listview], **xmlLayout**, **php service** which will upload image on ftp.

**Activity** :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        SharedPreferences sharedPref;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        ListView listview;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myfiles", MODE_PRIVATE);
            editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("0", "monika_pin.png");
            editor.putString("1", "monika_pin1.png");
            editor.putString("2", "monika_pin2.png");
            editor.commit();

            String[] arr = new String[] { "/mnt/sdcard/monika_pin.png",
                    "/mnt/sdcard/monika_pin1.png", "/mnt/sdcard/monika_pin2.png" };

            List<String> list = Arrays.asList(arr);

            MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem_imv, list);
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

            List<String> mList;
            LayoutInflater mInflater;
            int mResource;

            public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
                super(context, resource, objects);

                mResource = resource;
                mInflater = getLayoutInflater();
                mList = objects;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view;

                if (convertView == null) {
                    view = mInflater.inflate(mResource, null);
                } else {
                    view = convertView;
                }

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                imageView.setTag(mList.get(position));// tag of imageView == path to
                                                        // image
                new LoadImage(imageView).execute();
                textView.setText(mList.get(position).toString());

                return view;
            }
        }

        class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

            private ImageView imv;
            private String path;

            public LoadImage(ImageView imv) {
                this.imv = imv;
                this.path = imv.getTag().toString();
            }

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                // File file = new File(
                // Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                // path);
                File file = new File(path);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }

                return bitmap;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                if (!imv.getTag().toString().equals(path)) {
                    /*
                     * The path is not same. This means that this image view is
                     * handled by some other async task. We don't do anything and
                     * return.
                     */
                    return;
                }

                if (result != null && imv != null) {
                    imv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imv.setImageBitmap(result);
                } else {
                    imv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

        }

        public void buttonClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            startService(intent);
        }
    }
```

**Service** :

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    String upLoadServerUri = null;

    private static final String TAG = "com.example.ServiceExample";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("myfiles", MODE_PRIVATE);
        /************* Php script path ****************/
        upLoadServerUri = "http://myserver/uploadimage.php";

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand " + startId);

        final int currentId = startId;

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    // long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10*1000;

                    // while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        try {

                            uploadFile(sharedPref.getString(i + "", ""));

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }

                    }
                    // }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Service running " + currentId);
                }
                stopSelf();
            }
        };

        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        // File sourceFile = new
        // File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),sourceFileUri);
        File sourceFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName);
        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

            return 0;

        } else {
            try {

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                // dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_file";filename=""+ fileName + """
                // + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                }

                // close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                        "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            return serverResponseCode;

        } // End else block
    }

}
```

**XmlLayout** :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.service.MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.service"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <activity  
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**PhP Script** :

```
<?php

    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

**Note : Above sure where u create this php file on ftp, create a folder also called upload where all files will be uploaded**

If u wish to download complete Source code --> [Source Code](http://1drv.ms/1p7f2NM)

Comment: thank you very much :) i would recommend others to use this code for better results and awesome usage ! just great ...

Answer (score 3):

- don't forget to close the connection after you are done writing bytes `conn.close()`
- you don't need to use any `Runnables`/`Threads`

1) add the following interface to your `AsyncTask`:

```
    public interface onImageUploadListener{
     void onImageUploaded(String status);
     }
```

2) Declare its instance as a class field in your `AsyncTask` (I called it listener) and add the following constructor:

```
   public UploadFileAsync(onImageUploadListener listener){
         this.listener = listener;
    }
```

3) *Use `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` if you are on API >11 to prevent your upload task from blocking other tasks you might be running.*

4) Let your `Adapter` class (for god's sake, remove the `Runnable` part first) implement the interface:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements UploadFileAsync.onImageUploadListener
```

you will need to implement the `onImageUploaded(String status)` method:

```
           @Override
           public void  onImageUploaded(String status){
             //here you are getting your server response)
             //I use a bit of pseudo-code to describe this condition
               if(position < lastPosition){
                     new UploadFileAsync(this).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, String.valueOf(nextPosition));
                 }else{
                   //we are done
             }}
```

5) In your AsyncTask, assign the value of server response to some String and do the following on your `onPostExecute()` method:

```
     listener.onImageUploaded(yourResponseCode);
```

6) To force a 1-second delay, just call `Thread.sleep(1000);` inside your `doInBackground()` method just before the **return** statement.

The `onImageUploaded()` callback will be triggered each time your `AsyncTask` finishes, and you can execute it again and again from this method until you are done with upload. You can also add more checks to this method, for example check for error codes but this is up to you.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

First create a class like `ImageSyncService` posted here. Many components of this class are missing as I extracted it from my ongoing project, but you'll get the overview. If something is not clear you can ask me.

```
public class ImageSyncService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "ImageSyncService";

    private Image image;

    private ImageOpenHelper imageOpenHelper;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    public ImageSyncService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Logger.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent");

        imageOpenHelper = new ImageOpenHelper(getApplicationContext());
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        image = (Image) intent.getSerializableExtra(Config.REQUEST_EXTRA_OBJECT);
        if(image == null)
            return;

        if(image.getResourceURI() == null) {
            image.setSyncStatus(SyncStatus.SYNCING);
            imageOpenHelper.updateImage(image, false);

            Response response = MultiPartDataServer.postData(Config.URL_IMAGE_UPLOAD, nameValuePairs, null);
                        /* on success:
                         * 
                         * image.setSyncStatus(SyncStatus.SYNCED);
                         * imageOpenHelper.updateImage(image, false);
                         * 
                         * */ 
    }
}
```

On `uploadAll` button click do this:

```
    ArrayList<Image> images = imageOpenHelper.getUnsyncedImages(SyncStatus.TO_BE_UPLOADED);
    Intent imageSyncService = null;
    for(Image i: images) {
        imageSyncService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageSyncService.class);
        imageSyncService.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        imageSyncService.putExtra(Config.REQUEST_EXTRA_OBJECT, i);
        startService(imageSyncService);
    }
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I would just queue the `AsyncTask`s until no more pics are to be uploaded. Something like

```
if (++position < flags.size()) {
    new UploadFileAsync().execute(String.valueOf(position));
}
```

You could do this either in the `onPostExecute()` of AsyncTask or your `statusWhenFinished()` method. I'm not sure if you even need the Runnable...

HTH

Comment: still uploading all images together

Comment: You are closing theoutput stream, but are you also disconnection the HTTP Connection? It might keep open and in the next Task you don't open a new Connection but use the old one, since the URL is the same. So the Connection is used for multiple Pictures and can run into a timeout.

Comment: bro i need solution to upload multiple images one by one, still i am not concern about connection and all...

Answer (score 1):

**==== Activity Class From which image uploading will be triggered ====**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, ImageStatusUpdater{
    String img_url[] = new String[3];


    @Override
    public void onImageUpload(boolean status, String img_url) {
        //here you will get the status update with corresponding 
        //image url or say image name what ever
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        img_url[0] = "img1_url";
        img_url[1] = "img2_url";
        img_url[2] = "img3_url";

        new ImageUploader(this).execute(img_url);
    }

}
```

**=== Interface class will be used to update flag for each image after uploading from AsyncTask class ===**

```
public interface ImageStatusUpdater {
    public void onImageUpload(boolean status, String img_url);
}
```

**=== AsyncTask class from where actual uploading will be done ===**

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class ImageUploader extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>{

    ImageStatusUpdater isu;
    public ImageUploader(ImageStatusUpdater isu) {
        this.isu = isu;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        for (String img_name: params){
            //Here you have to write your uploading code

            String[] result;

            result = new String[1];
            result[0] = img_name;
            result[1] = "true";
            onProgressUpdate(result);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        this.isu.onImageUpload(Boolean.getBoolean(values[1]), values[0]);
    }

}
```

This is just a kind of demo code for explanation you the flow, you need to write actual code where ever appropriate.

Comment: But this uploads all 3 pics at once, which is exactly what the questioner wants to avoid.

Comment: it uploads one by one in loop. when one is done, its status is updated, then second iteration will happen with 2nd image details.

Comment: OK so it still depends on the uploading code which you omitted. @Moon also wrote a Loop but the pics where uploaded together. The problem should be in the Connection code.

Comment: yes i did not write the uploading code which he has to write. He has that ready. this solution i have used for downloading from multiple url one by one, so m sure it will surely work same for upload too.

Answer (score 1):

Easier method of uploading one by one is, Simply add `synchronised(mLock){ }` block in `doinBackground` function. Which keeps thet part of code mutually exclusive and only one image gets uploaded at a time. And its a **QuickFix or Workaround**, I don't prefer this method for this objective.

```
    // Async Upload
private static final Object mLock = new Object();//have an object to lock, and define out side the async task class
                                public class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

                                        String resServer;

                                protected void onPreExecute() {
                                        super.onPreExecute();
                                }

                                @Override
                                protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
synchronized(mLock){ //sync block starts
                                        position = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);

                                        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                                        byte[] buffer;
                                        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
                                        int resCode = 0;
                                        String resMessage = "";

                                        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                                        String twoHyphens = "--";
                                        String boundary =  "*****";

                                        // File Path
                                        String strSDPath = ImageList.get(position).toString();

                                        // Upload to PHP Script
                                    String strUrlServer = "";

                                        try {
                                                /** Check file on SD Card ***/
                                                File file = new File(strSDPath);
                                                if(!file.exists())
                                                {      
                                                        resServer = "{\"StatusID\":\"0\",\"Error\":\"Please check path on SD Card\"}";
                                                        return null;
                                                }

                                        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(strSDPath));

                                        URL url = new URL(strUrlServer);
                                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                                conn.setDoInput(true);
                                                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                                                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                                                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                                                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                                                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                                                                "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                                        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(conn
                                                        .getOutputStream());
                                                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                                                outputStream
                                                .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filUpload\";filename=\""
                                                                + strSDPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
                                                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                                        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                                        // Read file
                                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                                        while (bytesRead > 0) {
                                                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                                                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                                                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                                                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                                        }

                                        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                                        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                                        // Response Code and  Message
                                        resCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                                                if(resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                                                {
                                                        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                                                        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                                        int read = 0;
                                        while ((read = is.read()) != -1) {
                                                bos.write(read);
                                        }

                                        byte[] result = bos.toByteArray();
                                                bos.close();

                                        resMessage = new String(result);

                                        }

                                        Log.d("resCode=",Integer.toString(resCode));
                                        Log.d("resMessage=",resMessage.toString());

                                        fileInputStream.close();
                                        outputStream.flush();
                                        outputStream.close();

                                        resServer = resMessage.toString();


                                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                ex.printStackTrace();
                                        }
    }//Sync block ends
                                        return null;
                                        }

                                        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
                                                statusWhenFinish(position,resServer);
                                                }

                                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Looper`in a `WorkerThread` best suited for your requirement. Try it as follows -

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

   public static final int LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
   public static final MAX_IMAGE_INDEX = 500;
   public static final DELAY_TIME = 1*1000; // 1 second 
   private WorkerThread mWorkerThread;

   onCreate(Bundle bundle){
      mWorkerThread = new WorkerThread();
      mWorkerThread.start();
   }

   public void onCLick(View pView){

    Message message = Message.obtain();
    message.what = LOAD_IMAGE;
    message.arg1 = 0; // Start from Image index zero;
    mWorkerThread.queJob(message, 0);

   }

   private class WorkerThread{

      Looper looper;
      Handler handler;

      private void init(){
         if(!isAlive()){
            start();
         }
      }

      public void queJob(Message msg, int delay){

         init();
         if(handler!=null){
           handler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, delay);
         }
      }

      public void run(){

          Looper.prepare();
          looper = Looper.MyLoop();

          handler = new Handler(){

              public void handleMessage(Message msg){

                   if(msg.what==LOAD_IMAGE){

                        if(msg.agr1<0||msg.arg1>=MAX_IMAGE_INDEX)
                           return;
                        inr imageIndex = msg.arg1;

                        // Create connection here and load image

                        Message message = Message.obtain();
                        message.what = LOAD_IMAGE;
                        if(loadingSuccess){ // Load next image
                           message.agr1 = msg.arg1 + 1; // increase index to next 
                        }else{ // en que the same failed job
                            message.arg1 = msg.arg1;
                        }

                       queJob(message, DELAY_TIME);
                   }
              }
          };
          Looper.loop();

      }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         // down sizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
         // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```