# How to use file browser in android

Tags: android

I have an app for uploading files to a server using php! 
How can I implement file browser in my app to select which file to be uploaded! ?
Please give me very simple example ! Or simple solution!

Comment: u can open dialog for files listed in sdcard and for upload watch this -->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731838/loop-to-upload-list-images-one-by-one/24894589#24894589

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many solutions for this on google, and here you can't just ask for a full implementation and expect someone to write it here. Here are a couple of good results:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/

http://android-er.blogspot.pt/2010/01/implement-simple-file-explorer-in.html

Basically you will have a list dialog that will search for files and directories on your sdcard, then if it is a file (there are methods in File class to check if it is file or directory for example) then choose it and dismiss the dialog, or if it is a directory, change directory and refresh dialog with list of files and directories and so on.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to select any type of file there's no simple solution, you'll have to implement a file manager-similar functionality. Here are some tips and samples to get you started:

prerequisites: your have some basic understanding for how Android works; you know how to implement a custom `ListView`

- use `ListView` to display the files
- parametrize your `Adapter` with an `ArrayList<File>`

start with the root of external storage:

```
 File root = Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

the following method will list all files and subdirs in a directory:

```
    public static ArrayList<File> getSubfiles(File root) {

    File[] mFiles = root.listFiles();

    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    ArrayList<File> dirs = new ArrayList<File>();
    ArrayList<File> allData = new ArrayList<File>();
    for (int i = 0; i < myFiles.length; i++) {

        if (!myFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            files.add(myFiles[i]);
        } else {
            dirs.add(myFiles[i]);
        }

     }
    Collections.sort(files);
    Collections.sort(dirs);
    allData.addAll(dirs);
    allData.addAll(files);

    return allData;

}
```

using this method you can move "down" the file system by passing any directory to it. To move up, simply use `getParentFile()` and pass the result to this method.

So you should always pass the result of this method to your Adapter, calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` afterwards.

That's all, you have a very basic file viewer. Of course you will need to create some layouts and write a bit more of code, the above tips should help you to get started, since as was already mentioned nobody is going to write half of your app for you here on SO. If you have further questions/problems leave a comment and describe your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to select the file path try the [Android-Simple-File-Explorer-Library](https://github.com/BalioFVFX/Android-Simple-File-Explorer-Library)

First show the file explorer:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CONTEXT, SimpleFileExplorerActivity);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

And then receive the result:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if(data != null){
        String selectedAbsolutePath = data.getStringExtra(SimpleFileExplorerActivity.ON_ACTIVITY_RESULT_KEY);
        Toast.makeText(CONTEXT, selectedAbsolutePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
    }
}
```